# Data Feed Thread Executing Trading Strategies?

Tags: java, multithreading, trading, algorithmic-trading

As you know, trading strategies take actions based on real time feed, such as when the bid or the last trade price changes. A data feed provider streams quotes to our desktop application asynchronously in a separate thread from the main thread. This data feed thread is spawned when you make a request to the data feed provider and lives until you explictly send a request to stop the streaming.

As it stands, the data feed thread executes trading strategies because most of them are designed to enter or update orders upon tick data. Do you see any problem with this approach? Is this design common in trading applications?

I'm using Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely don't want to execute a trading strategy on the data feed thread, particularly if the execution takes a while. That execution should happen on a different thread. I am not that familiar with Java, but I assume you could make use of a thread pool there. In C# a very powerful way to spread out work over multiple threads would be using [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx).

Another thing you might want to think about is what to do when there are new ticks for an instrument while you are still processing the previous tick. In many cases it makes sense to only process the most recent one. I have written up a little post on what I termed the [most recent update pattern](https://personalnexus.wordpress.com/2011/02/27/a-modest-proposal-the-most-recent-update-pattern) with a sample implementation in C#. Maybe you find that useful.

Answer (score 1):

> As it stands, the data feed thread executes trading strategies because most of them are designed to enter or update orders upon tick data.

Not quite.  The data feed thread **triggers the execution** of trading strategies.  You don't want any other processing to slow down the data feed thread.

Comment: Thanks, should I spawn a new thread for trading strategy execution for every tick data?

Comment: @Tom Tucker: My answer will depend somewhat on what language you're using.  The data feed thread should send a signal for each tick to a supervisor thread that determines if this tick is an element of one of your trading strategies.  If so, the supervisor thread will determine if all of the elements of a particular trading strategy are in place.  If so, the supervisor thread starts a trading thread to execute the particular trading strategy.  The supervisor thread has to queue the ticks, so it doesn't lose any tick data while determining which trading thread(s) to execute.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using Java BTW.